# Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

I am reading from Brodmann, Sharp *Local Cohomology* about Castelnuovo-Mumford (CM)-regularity, and although I think had understood some things about it I got stuck in an exercise which wants to prove that $\mathrm{reg}(R_0[X_1,...,X_n])=0$, for $R_0$ commutative, Noetherian ring. Although that fits in my intuition so far, that is, CM-regularity measures in a sense the complexity of a given module $M$ in terms of its free graded resolution I can't really understand why is $0$ based on its definition only.

Also in some other example (which apparently is related), they prove that 
$$H^n_{(X_1,...,X_n)}(R_0[X_1,...,X_n]) \cong R_0[X^{-}_1,...,X^{-}_n], \thinspace.$$
where the latter is the *"module of inverse polynomials over $R_0$"*. Again although the construction of it makes sense, I have a problem understand its grading, since inside the book for some it's described quite complicate.

Can you please help me sort out the above? Thank you!

Comment: What the definition of regularity in the book? Do you have answers to your questions when the cofficient ring is a field?

Comment: I guess is the usual one $\mathrm{reg}(M)= sup \{end(H^i_{R_+}(M)+i | i \in \{0,...,dim(M)\} \}$.

Comment: Regarding the second question, the regularity works over *any* commutative Noetherian ring the same. I mean for $R_0$ an arbitrary such a ring, $\mathrm{reg}(R_0[X_1,...,X_n])=0$

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer you question when $R_0 = k$ a field. Let $S = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Then $x_1, \dots, x_n$ forms an $S$-regular seqeunce. Hence $H^i_m (S) = 0$ unless $i = n$, where $m = (x_1, \dots, x_n)S$.

One can compute the local cohomology modules using the Cech complex with respect to $x_1,\dots, x_n$. Then it is easy to observe that
$$
H^n_m (S) = \{ x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n} \mid a_i \le -1\}
$$
as $k$-vector spaces
by analyzing the tail of the Cech complex
$$
\oplus S_{x_1\cdots \hat{x_l} \cdots x_n} \to S_{x_1\cdots x_n} \to 0.
$$
Here $\hat{x_l}$ means omitting $x_l$. Hence $\sup \{ i \mid [H^n_m(S)]_i \neq 0\} = -n$ as everything respects grading. This answers your first question.

I am not familiar with the concept of the module of inverse polynomials over $k$. However, the right hand side of 
$$
H^n_m (S) = \{ x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n} \mid a_i \le -1\}
$$
is isomorphic to $\frac{1}{x_1\cdots x_n} k[x_1^{-1}, \dots, x_n^{-1}]$ as $k[x_1^{-1}, \dots, x_n^{-1}]$-modules.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I'll read it through, but seems to be useful. One question, in your last sentence what the notation $\frac{1}{x_1...x_n} k[x^{-1}_1,...,x^{-1}_n]$ means? You mean probably the principal ideal generated by this element?

Comment: Also the part $\sup \{ i \mid [H^n_m(S)]_i \neq 0\} = -n$ is incomprehensible in my head. Clearly because I don't understand the grading of $H^n_m(S)$. However why for any integer $i>-n$, $H^i_m(S) =0$?

Comment: That’s correct. For the second comment, I suggest you to draw pictures for the case when n = 1,2.